# Filter mySQL data while using fetchall(), before passing rows into Excel, via DataNitro

Tags: python, mysql, excel, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am trying to simplify this so it will pull any data and lay out without any conflict, but I find errors if I have a date structure with colons and if some of my products have uses of backslash or code like characters. Any way to strip or contain these in a string if existing? Here is my simple process using MySQLdb...

```
c = db.cursor()
exstring = "SELECT id,model,upc,date,cost FROM products"
CellRange("A5:I600").clear() # cleanup existing data
c.execute(exstring)
sh = c.fetchall()
for i, pos in enumerate(sh):
    Cell(5+i, 1).horizontal = pos #starts 5th row
```

A lot of the errors for these types of dates (datetime)...

```
2013-06-01 05:15:02
```

Get a list of 27/basic_io.py errors, as well as global name 'logging' is not defined.

```
File "27/basic_io.py", line 352, in __setattr__
File "27/basic_io.py", line 238, in _set_horizontal
File "27/basic_io.py", line 607, in __setattr__
File "27/basic_io.py", line 352, in __setattr__
File "27/basic_io.py", line 167, in _set_value
Namerror: global name 'logging' is not defined
```

But if I select basic data it all works good. I would like to get to the point of a SELECT * and it will pull back any table structure without any issues. If not possible, then a way to filter individual columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataNitro added improved support for datetime types in the latest release (https://datanitro.com/pro/auth/login).  Try it out and see if it solves the problem - you should be able to run the original script without using date formatting now.

Source: I'm one of the DataNitro developers.

Comment: I ran it and all is good! Thank you, great service and product.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the `27/basic_io.py` file is, but it sounds like the problem is that it can't cope with objects from Python's [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module.

Try `SELECT`ing the `date` column as a string instead with...

```
exstring = 'SELECT id,model,upc,DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d"),cost FROM products'
```

You can vary the returned format by using different format specifiers in [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: That removed the error, I believe that will help a lot if I research DATE_FORMAT(), thanks!